# How could I change my Python code so that it could convert txt file to CSV more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I recently learned Python and started to develop code that could read and cleanse the data. In the below code, I am trying to read approximately 200 txt files of 200 MBs each with a | delimiter and trying to merge them into a single CSV file with 1 particular thing changed. The source files have negative numbers where the negative signs are at the end of the number. e.g. 221.36- 111- etc. I need to convert these to -221.36 and -111.

This currently takes around 100 minutes to process 80 Million records. Since this is only my 2nd or 3rd code written in Python, I am looking for your opinion on how to optimize this code. Any best practices you could suggest before it is ready to be go into production would be of great help.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv
import glob

# List out all files that needs to be used as Input
list_of_input_files = (glob.glob("C:/Users/datafolder/pattern*"))
with open('C:/Users/datafolder/tempfile.txt','wb') as wfd:
     for f in list_of_input_files:
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024*1024*10)
print('File Merge Complete')

# Create temporary files for processing
txt_file = "C:/Users/datafolder/tempfile.txt"
csv_file = "C:/Users/datafolder/mergedcsv.csv"

# Write CSV file after reading data from a txt file. Converts delimeter from '|' to ','
with open(txt_file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_pipe:
    with open(csv_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file_comma: #newline paramater to ignore blank lines in the final file
        csv.writer(file_comma, delimiter=',').writerows(csv.reader(file_pipe, delimiter='|'))

print('CSV File Created.')

tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding='utf-8', delete=False)

# Data Definition
fields = ['Field 1','Field 2','Field 3,'Field 4','Field 5','Field 6','Field 7','Field 8','Field 9','Field 10','Field 11','Field 12','Field 13','Field 14','Field 15','Field 16','Field 17,'Field 18','Field 19','Field 20']

count=0
# Open files in read and write modes for data processing
with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields) #Using a Python dictionary to read and write data into a CSV file.
    writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fields, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
       if count < 1000000:
          if row['Field 10'].endswith('-'):
             row['Field 10']=float(row['Field 10'].replace('-',''))*(-1) #Trims - sign from the end of line, converts the target field to Float and makes it negative
          count=count+1
       else:
          print('1 Million records Processed')
          count=0

         # Creating a row for final write
       row={'Field 1' : row['Field 1'],'Field 2' : row['Field 2'],'Field 3  : row['Field 3 ],'Field 4' : row['Field 4'],'Field 5' : row['Field 5'],'Field 6' : row['Field 6'],'Field 7' : row['Field 7'],'Field 8' : row['Field 8'],'Field 9' : row['Field 9'],'Field 10' : row['Field 10'],'Field 11' : row['Field 11'],'Field 12' : row['Field 12'],'Field 13' : row['Field 13'],'Field 14' : row['Field 14'],'Field 15' : row['Field 15'],'Field 16' : row['Field 16'],'Field 17' : row['Field 17'],'Field 18' : row['Field 18'],'Field 19' : row['Field 19'],'Field 20' : row['Field 20']}
       writer.writerow(row) # Writer write rows to the CSV File
    print('Data write to CSV file complete')

# Renaming the newly created temp file as the final file. New file now has fully processed data.            
shutil.move(tempfile.name, csv_file)
print('Renaming Complete')
```

Comment: You may find this article useful: https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/BigONotation.html

Comment: If the code works it's off-topic here. You might have better luck on [codereview.se].

Comment: Don't loop over the rows twice. Get a row from the original file, change all the negative values, then write it to the new file. You also don't need to pre-merge. Also, you might want to look into `multiprocessing` to do parallel processing, but it's a bit much to get into here.

Comment: You may gain speed by using regular expressions rathr than things like 'endswith' and 'replace'.'

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge regex is almost certainly slower than string methods

Comment: According to what is outlined in: "Code Review or not?" this post is on-topic for Stack Overflow because it seeks to solve a specific problem (the code doesn't complete in a timely enough manner):
https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778

Comment: @JohnStark, in order to be on-topic here I'd expect a [mcve] and a more specific problem statement. IMO this is too open-ended to be a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reasoning behind using `csv.DictReader` as opposed to just `csv.reader`? Using `csv.reader` would allow you to access row data via index, rather than using keys like `'Field 10'`:

```
if row[9].endswith('-'):
    row[9]=float(row[9].replace('-',''))*(-1)
```

This would eliminate the need for the code on line 51, which would speed up the program a bit, as you could simply call `writer.writerow(row)` with the `row` that you already have, since it will already be a tuple.

Using `csv.reader` would also afford another small optimization. Currently you're checking if `count < 1000000` every single time you go through the loop, and also incrementing the `count` variable. Instead you could do something like this:

```
row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
if row_count >= 1000000:
    row_count = 1000000

for i in itertools.islice(reader, row_count):
    // trim logic

if row_count == 1000000:
    print('1 Million records Processed')
```

That removes the conditional check, and the incrementation of the count variable which, over the course of 80 million iterations could add up to some actual time saved.

Comment: Thank you, John. I just tried to emulate what some coders suggested here on a different post. I probably don't need to use the DictReader. Your solution foes look a lot more efficient. I will give this a try and post an update.

Comment: `csv.reader` objects don't have a `len`. Use `itertools.islice(reader, 1000000)`

Comment: Why there is a requirement of fields?

Comment: @JohnStark I just made a change and replace csv.DictReader with csv.reader. It shaved of 35 mins off the run-time. I actually tried to implement itertools but i couldn't grasp it's concept. From what i got, it just creates list of the number specified and once there, it stops. What happens to the rest of the records and where do i get it to print the counts once a Million record milestone is reached. Anyways, one step at a time. I will do my research on it next. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Hardy 35% reduction in runtime is pretty good for changing up your data structure! I've updated my answer to show how you would use `itertools.islice()` to run the loop and still print out the 1 million records notification.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much through your code, I suspect you can reduce the memory footprint by using a generator to read the files line-by-line instead of all at once.

It would look something like this:

```
for line in open('really_big_file.csv'):
    do_something(line)
```

Also, `csv.DictReader` is likely slower than other methods of reading files purely because it needs to build a hash table for every line. Reading the results to a `tuple` would likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and it's `read_csv()` function. You could tell it to split on '|' and then modify the column values to fix up the negative signs. Then tell it to write out the new CSV file using `to_csv()`.